# pointer to member of struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to write a C program. I need the address of variable "recq". Can someone pls help me figure that out?

```
typedef struct {  
    int recq;  
} dd;  


struct test {  
    dd a;  
};

main(){  
    struct test *mm;  
    mm=(struct test *) malloc (sizeof (struct test));    
    ss=&(mm->a.recq);    
    printf("%p",ss);    

}
```

Comment: Other than a missing declaration of 'ss', the code you've provided will get the address of a member of a structure. Can you provide more detail on what isn't working for you?

Comment: Extermely sorry, was doing a very silly error. While making the last correction, I realised it. Its working now. The code pasted above in question works! :) Sorry again.

Answer (score 5):

What you have looks good except you need to declare the ss variable:

```
int *ss;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare `ss` as "int * " , or use cast whatever
the rest of your code is right, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your required program is,

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int recq;  
} dd;  

struct test {  
    dd a;  
};

void main(void){
    struct test mm;
    printf("%p", &mm.a.recq);
}
```