# Last N lines with a list of Strings in C

Tags: c, list

I'm making a program which prints the N last lines of an input with an unknown number of lines. My problem is that it prints N times the last line. I think it's because fgets modifies "linea" and the element value of all nodes is modified as well.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo{
    char* elemento; //string which contains
    struct nodo *siguiente; //next element
    };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int N = 7;
    char linea[1024];
    struct nodo *lineas; //lineas is the head of the list
    struct nodo *aux; //last node
    struct nodo *aux2; //to remove first node if necessary
    lineas= (struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo)); 

    int i=1;
    if (NULL!=fgets(linea, 1024, stdin)){ //It stops if Control + D or End of File
        lineas->elemento=linea; //We Initialize the list with the first String
        lineas->siguiente=NULL;
        aux=lineas;

        while (NULL!=fgets(linea, 1024, stdin)){

            if (i<N){ //If i hasn't reach N, we add at the end
                aux->siguiente=(struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
                aux=aux->siguiente;
                aux->elemento=linea;
                aux->siguiente=NULL;
                i++;            
            }
            else{ //If we already have N elements, remove first and add by the end          
                aux2=lineas;
                lineas=lineas->siguiente;
                free(aux2);

                aux->siguiente=(struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
                aux=aux->siguiente;
                aux->elemento=linea;
                aux->siguiente=NULL;                        
            }   
        }
        while(lineas!=NULL){ //Print and free memory
            printf("%s",lineas->elemento);
            aux=lineas;
            lineas=lineas->siguiente;
            free(aux);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First order of business is to get used to employing English identifiers. You aren't the only who'll have to read you code, most workplaces and even open-source project are global. Your'e even limiting the amount of people who can read your code without straining themselves on SO, and thus the amount of people that can help you.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the confussion I hope the comments in English were helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right, there is only storage for one line. The giveaway is that there is only ever enough memory allocated for one line, on this line:

```
char linea[1024];
```

In the other places where chunks of memory are allocated, like this:

```
aux->siguiente=(struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
```

only enough memory to hold a `nodo` is allocated, but that is just enough space for two pointers, not for a whole line. All of the `elemento=linea` assignments store pointers to the single `char linea[1024]`.

Comment: Would it be a solution assigning enough memory for N lines (linea[N][1024]) and work like that, or is there an easier way? Thanks

<<EDIT>>
I've tried to change the node and put char elemento[1024] so it can store the line itself, but fgets saves in "linea" a char*, how can I save it?

Comment: `fgets` takes a pointer to the buffer, and the buffer is a member of the `nodo` struct, so you want [a pointer to a member of a struct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10280717/119271). That looks like: `fgets(&aux.elemento, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it changing char linea[1024] to char *linea and doing malloc every time I needed a new line.

This is the code (translated to English): Changes are noted with ##:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct nodo{
    char* element; //string which contains
    struct nodo *next; //next node
    };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   

    int N=7;
    char* line; //##
    struct nodo *lines; //head of the list
    struct nodo *aux; //last node of the list
    struct nodo *aux2; //to help removing first nodes
    lines= (struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    int i=1; //first string
    line= (char*) malloc(1024*sizeof(char)); //##
    fgets(line, 1024, stdin); //##
    if (line[0]!='\0'){ //##
        lines->element=line; //Initialize list with the first line
        lines->next=NULL;
        aux=lines;

        line= (char*) malloc(1024*sizeof(char)); // ## second line
        fgets(line, 1024, stdin); //##

        while (line[0]!='\0'){ //##

            if (i<N){ //Si i hasn't reach N, we add at the end
                aux->next=(struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
                aux=aux->next;
                aux->element=line;
                aux->next=NULL;
                i++;            
            }
            else{ //If we already have N elements, remove first and add by the end          
                aux2=lines;
                lines=lines->next;
                free(aux2);

                aux->next=(struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
                aux=aux->next;
                aux->element=line;
                aux->next=NULL;                     
            }
        line= (char*) malloc(1024*sizeof(char)); //##
        fgets(line, 1024, stdin); //##
        }
        while(lines!=NULL){ //Print and free memory
            printf("%s",lines->element);
            aux=lines;
            lines=lines->next;
            free(aux);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Maybe I've left some free();